# Python xml.etree formatting beautify?

Tags: python, xml, string

I got a script that uses xml.etree.ElementTree to parse an XML-file and is supposed to add a child to an element. I have two approaches, that both work technically but both result in messed up formatting/whitespace when I dump the whole xml using ET.dump(root)

First method I use fromstring

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

#snip

newgroup='''
    <group>
        <uuid>%s</uuid>
        <id>%s</id>
        <name>%s</name>
        <desc>%s</desc>
    </group>            
''' % (g_uuid, g_id, g_name, g_desc)

access = root.find('access')
access.append(ET.fromstring(newgroup))
```

This results in the group being added as a child, but after endtag of group is no newline and the first tag only has 1 tab, no matter how many tabulators I put into the newgroup string.

```
<group>
        <uuid>f60e6b30-eec9-11e6-a5d4-2c768aabceca</uuid>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>newgroup</name>
        <desc>Testing groups</desc>
    </group></access>
```

I wonder why it takes the whitespaces correctly for the childs of group but messes up the formatting of the group tags itself.

Second method was building an etree of the group with it's children

```
newgroup = ET.Element('group')
ET.SubElement(newgroup, 'uuid').text = '%s' % g_uuid
ET.SubElement(newgroup, 'id').text = '%s' % g_id
ET.SubElement(newgroup, 'name').text = '%s' % g_name
ET.SubElement(newgroup, 'desc').text = '%s' % g_desc

access = root.find('access')
access.append(newgroup)
```

But then the whole newgroup-tree appears in a single line without newlines and tabs at all:

```
<group><uuid>f60e6b30-eec9-11e6-a5d4-2c768aabceca</uuid><id>2</id><name>newgroup</name><desc>Testing groups</desc></group></access>
```

I am new to python and don't really know how to format strings. So how can I beautify this thing so that I get well formatted XML out of the script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use any approach to create your XML **without** any worrying about formatting, and then just use universal indent function like this on your root element:

```
def indent(elem, level=0, hor='\t', ver='\n'):
    i = ver + level * hor
    if len(elem):
        if not elem.text or not elem.text.strip():
            elem.text = i + hor
        if not elem.tail or not elem.tail.strip():
            elem.tail = i
        for elem in elem:
            indent(elem, level + 1, hor, ver)
        if not elem.tail or not elem.tail.strip():
            elem.tail = i
    else:
        if level and (not elem.tail or not elem.tail.strip()):
            elem.tail = i
```

Another solution is use the `lxml` third-party library, that already has similar effect when writing to a file with keyword argument `pretty_print=True`. By the way, this is almost non-configurable approach. So, with custom indent functions you may configure any behavior you want learning on this example.

Comment: I fixed recursive call with hor and ver arguments (without this, they would work improperly if not default). Also, please, vote for answer (upside triangle) together with approval. Thank you.